# Docusign Embedded Signing/ Power Form without entering signer information

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to sign on a envelope without entering the user information such as email-id in the case of embedded signing?

Is it possible to sign a power form without entering the details like name & email-id?

Basic idea about requirement

User fills out a form

Clicking on a button will load the power form/ embedded signing envelope url on a iframe or something like that.

Condition 1 :In case of [Power Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBvb6.png) we have to enter the information like mail-id and name to load the document and begin signing.

Our requirement is to sign the document without entering user information.
(Like skipping the Condition 1)

In the case of Envelope Url, the signers need to login. How can we sign the envelope without login/user information?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it requires some additional setup on the template the PowerForm is based on. What you need to do is lock the recipient from being editable, then place a full name and email tab on the template itself. When the PowerForm link is engaged, it should take the recipient directly into the signing session where the Full Name and Email are required tabs that they must fill prior to completing the envelope.

An overview of the process can be found here: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-bypass-powerform-signer-info-page

Regards,
Matt